# CDI: Injection based on object class

Tags: java, cdi

I have class hierarchy where I would like to inject field using CDI based on type of subclass.
This situation is described in following Java code:

```
@Stateless
public class A {
    @Inject
    @MyInjection
    D d;
    ...
    public void templateMethod(){...};
    protected void step1(){...};
    protected void step2(){...};
}

@Stateless
public class B extends A {
...
    protected void step1(){...};
    protected void step2(){...};
}

@Stateless
public class C extends A {
...
    protected void step1(){...};
    protected void step2(){...};
}

public class F {

    @Produces
    @MyInjection
    D myProducer(InjectionPoint ip){
        Class<?> clazz = ip.getMember().getDeclaringClass();

        //if clazz is B then inject one type

        //if clazz is C then inject other type

        //default inject default type
    }
}
```

These beans are packaged appropriate ejb.jar archive as part of EAR and there is beans.xml file in proper place. The code is executing on Wildfly 10 server using Java EE 7.

Using this code I get class of hierarchy base class (in this specific case class A), which is when I think about it logical, beacause InjectionPoint
field is indeed in class A.
The point is that I would like to make distinction based on subclasses although I do inject in superclass.

Could I achieve this using InjectionPoint class? Is there any possible way to achieve this?

More on that what I would like to achieve with this piece of code. This hierarchy implements template method Design Pattern and all classes are concrete, you can use class A which implements general algorithm and specific steps, but you can opt out to redefine steps in some subclass. Also there is need to inject specific type D, which might be different based on sublclass.

Unfortunately there is strong desire not to redesign bass class A. So I am trying to find I way to inject something in base class using CDI and not using deployment descriptor.

Comment: please mention in your question everything you tried

Answer (score 2):

From your question I understood that you want to determine what **bean** are you injecting it into. This can be achieved in the following way:

```
@Produces
@MyInjection
D myProducer(InjectionPoint ip){
    // this will give you the class of the bean you injected into
    ip.getBean().getBeanClass();
}
```

For completeness, your previous solution used `ip.getMember()` which returns a `Method` objects (or `Field` for field producers). Therefore, subsequent call to `getDeclaringClass()` will give you `class A`.

Comment: Siliarus thanks for your answer, but unfortunenatelly ip.getBean() in my particular case returns null. For the time being it's a puzzle for me.

Comment: Returning null? Well, that probably means you have "wrong" scopes on beans. Because `InjectionPoint` only works if you are injecting into `@Dependent` bean (read more [here](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#injection_point)). What is the scope of your `A`, `B` and `C` beans?

Comment: I believe it's `@Dependent`. As far as I know `@Dependent` is default scope if bean is not annotated. Am I wrong?

Comment: Oh, I see you've updated you question - your beans are `@Stateless`. That won't work for you - the spec does not define how to handle that. `@Stateless` beans are usually (not always! server dependent!) a pool of beans reused for requests - from that perspective its nearly impossible for CDI to know which bean injected it originally (or later on). And for the same reason you shouldn't rely on that. Therefore, Weld choses to return `null` instead. There is a recent [WELD issue](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WELD-2341) where this was discussed. NOTE: should work in bussiness method invocation.

Comment: Oh, I see. I was not aware of that. Thanks a lot. Well after a little bit of tinkering I achieved what i wanted. It does require a small change in base class, but for the time being I can't figure out other solution. If interested please look my answer to own question.

Comment: A very good idea! The problem with SLSB exists only if you do `ip.getBean()`, which you nicely avoided.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of tinkering I found a way to achieve behaviour stated in my question. This required different approach to CDI injection: instead of field injection **constructor injection** did the job.

```
public class A {
    D d;
    ...

    public A(){
        this.d = null;
    }

    @Inject
    public A(@MyInjection D d){
        this.d = d;
    }
    ...
    public void templateMethod(){...};
    protected void step1(){...};
    protected void step2(){...};
}

@Stateless
public class B extends A {
    ...
    public B(){
        super();
    }

    @Inject
    public B(@MyInjection D d){
        super(d);
    }
    ...
    protected void step1(){...};
    protected void step2(){...};
}

@Stateless
public class C extends A {
    ...
    public B(){
        super();
    }

    @Inject
    public B(@MyInjection D d){
        super(d);
    }
    ...
    protected void step1(){...};
    protected void step2(){...};
}

public class F {

    @Produces
    @MyInjection
    D myProducer(InjectionPoint ip){
        Class<?> clazz = ip.getMember().getDeclaringClass();

        //if clazz is B then inject one type

        //if clazz is C then inject other type

        //default inject default type
    }
}
```

Organizing code this way I am able to discriminate injection based on leaf classes, although the requirement of not changing code of the base class (part of an API) might not be possible to achieve.